# Aligning molecules

Tags: chemfig

I'm writing a reaction of hydrolysis, but the glucose isn't aligned with the sucrose nor the fructose. Help.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{HO-[2,.5,2]?<[7,.7](-[2,.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[6,.5]OH)>[1,.7](-[:-65,.7]O-[:65,.7]?[b](-[2,.7]CH_2OH)<[:-60,.707](-[6,.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[2,.5,,2]HO)>[:60,.707](-[6,.5]CH_2OH)-[:162,.9]O?[b])-[3,.7]O-[4]?(-[2,.3]-[3,.5]HO)}
\arrow{<=>}
\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{HO-[2,0.5,2]?<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]OH)-[,,,,
line width=2.4pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)-[3,0.7]
O-[4]?(-[2,0.3]-[3,0.5]OH)}
\+
\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{(?[b](-[2,.7]CH_2OH)<[:-60,.707](-[6,.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[2,.5,,2]HO)>[:60,.707](-[6,.5]CH_2OH)-[:162,.9]O?[b])}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image: Current Output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [manual ver 1.41](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig?lang=en) in section 12, *The + sign*, it states that you can vertically align the + if you add `\arrow{0}[,0]` which draws an invisible arrow of zero-length. In your case, you need to put that hack right after the + sign as well, *i.e.,* `\arrow{0}[,0]\+\arrow{0}[,0]`.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{HO-[2,.5,2]?<[7,.7](-[2,.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[6,.5]OH)>[1,.7](-[:-65,.7]O-[:65,.7]?[b](-[2,.7]CH_2OH)<[:-60,.707](-[6,.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[2,.5,,2]HO)>[:60,.707](-[6,.5]CH_2OH)-[:162,.9]O?[b])-[3,.7]O-[4]?(-[2,.3]-[3,.5]HO)}
\arrow{<=>}
\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{HO-[2,0.5,2]?<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)-[3,0.7]O-[4]?(-[2,0.3]-[3,0.5]OH)}
\arrow{0}[,0]\+\arrow{0}[,0]
\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{(?[b](-[2,.7]CH_2OH)<[:-60,.707](-[6,.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[2,.5,,2]HO)>[:60,.707](-[6,.5]CH_2OH)-[:162,.9]O?[b])}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```