# Draw Saccharides

Tags: chemfig

I would like to draw the following two pictures ([source1](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c6/Alpha-D-Glucopyranose.svg/640px-Alpha-D-Glucopyranose.svg.png), [source2](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Saccharose2.svg/345px-Saccharose2.svg.png)) using [`chemfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) but I have no idea how to do it:

[image]

[image]

I can copy paste the example from the bottom of page 41 of the manual (and make marginally changes) to almost get the first molecule:

```
% lualatex test.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \chemfig[cram width=2pt]
    {HO-[2,0.5,2]?<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)
    -[3,0.7]O-[4]?(-[2,0.3]-[3,0.5]CH_2OH)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Problems**

- How do I make the bond connecting the `CH_2OH` part to the rest of the molecule to 'link' at the first `C` instead of at the last `H`?
- I have no idea how to draw the second saccharide at all; I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/carbohydrates or here https://www.ctan.org/author/niederberger . And here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505870/aligning-molecules .

Comment: @MS-SPO That was exactly what I needed -- thanks alot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There you are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{
    HO
    -[2,0.5,2]?
    <[7,0.7](
        -[2,0.5]OH
    )
    -[,,,,line width=2pt](
        -[6,0.5]OH
    )
    >[1,0.7](
        -[6,0.5]OH
    )
    -[3,0.7]O
    -[4]?(
        -[2,0.5]CH_2OH
    )
}

\bigskip

\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{
    HO
    -[2,0.5,2]?[a]
    <[7,0.7](
        -[2,0.5]OH
    )
    -[,,,,line width=2pt](
        -[6,0.5]OH
    )
    >[1,0.7](
        -[:-60,0.7]O
        -[:60,0.7]?[b](
            -[2]CH_2OH
        )
        <[7,0.7](
            -[6,0.5]OH
        )
        -[,,,,line width=2pt](
            -[2,0.5,,2]HO
        )
        >[1,0.7](
            -[6,0.5]CH_2OH
        )
        -[:150,1.15]O?[b]
    )
    -[3,0.7]O
    -[4]?[a](
        -[2,0.5]CH_2OH
    )
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to connect to a specific atom in a molecule, you can do this by using the fourth vaue of the option chain. Compare:

```
\chemfig{X-[:90]CH_2OH} 
\chemfig{X-[:90,,,3]CH_2OH}
```

[image]

In the somewhat complicated second case, you need to use named hooks, because you need two of them for each ring. So, instead of just using `?`, you can use `?[a]` and `?[b]`.

Finally, you can also use degrees for the first value of the option chain for bonds. Just prefix the degree values with a colon: `:60`. This comes in handy for the second molecule when placing the oxygen atoms.

---

To remove the small caps at the cram bonds, you can make use of a few tricks using Ti*k*Z (not perfect, but probably not visible when printed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\tikzset{
    thick bond/.style={
        line width=2pt, 
        line cap=round,
        shorten >=-.25pt,
        shorten <=-.25pt
    }
}

\begin{document}

\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{
    HO
    -[2,0.5,2]?
    <[7,0.7](
        -[2,0.5]OH
    )
    -[,,,,thick bond](
        -[6,0.5]OH
    )
    >[1,0.7](
        -[6,0.5]OH
    )
    -[3,0.7]O
    -[4]?(
        -[2,0.5]CH_2OH
    )
}

\bigskip

\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{
    HO
    -[2,0.5,2]?[a]
    <[7,0.7](
        -[2,0.5]OH
    )
    -[,,,,thick bond](
        -[6,0.5]OH
    )
    >[1,0.7](
        -[:-60,0.7]O
        -[:60,0.7]?[b](
            -[2]CH_2OH
        )
        <[7,0.7](
            -[6,0.5]OH
        )
        -[,,,,thick bond](
            -[2,0.5,,2]HO
        )
        >[1,0.7](
            -[6,0.5]CH_2OH
        )
        -[:150,1.15]O?[b]
    )
    -[3,0.7]O
    -[4]?[a](
        -[2,0.5]CH_2OH
    )
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

1. use "[3,.5,,1] at bond connecting CH2OH

The number 1 indicates the carbon of arrival of the bond
-[angle,lenght,start atom,arrival atom,...]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \chemfig[cram width=2pt]
        {HO-[2,0.5,2]?<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)
            -[3,0.7]O-[4]?(-[2,0.3]-[3,0.5,,1]CH_2OH)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2. basically, place a copy of the first part on the correct carbon and add the CH2OH

long distance connections will need to be named

?[a] -- ?[a] and ?[b] -- ?[b]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig[cram width=2pt]
        {HO-[2,0.5,2]?[a]<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[:300]O-[:60]?[b](-[2,.7,,1]CH_2OH)<[7,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2pt](-[2,.5,,2]HO)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]CH_2OH)-[:160,1.1]O?[b])
            -[3,0.7]O-[4]?[a](-[2,0.5,,1]CH_2OH)}
\end{document}
```

[image]